Possible Bayes Theorom Rigged Coin Problem
You have 3 coins. 2 of them are fair; one is rigged so that it always lands on heads. You choose a coin at random and flip it; it lands on heads. Is the coin: fair, rigged or equally likely?
I get Bayes theorem gives that it’s equally likely. But I have a hard time explaining why the following intuition is wrong:
I have a coin that flipped to heads. I then tell you it came from either these 2 fair coins or a rigged coin that only lands on heads. Since we started with heads, we know the rigged coin is a possibility so we go back to the probability of picking each coin (2/3 fair 1/3 rigged). Other words, once I tell you we have heads, there are 3 possibilities. Fair1 heads, Fair2 heads, and rigged. So still 2/3 fair 1/3 rigged. Why is this wrong?

Short answer: because the probability of the rigged coin landing heads is not the same as the probability of a fair coin landing heads. If you think about it, there are 6 outcomes (2 of which are rigged, heads) 4 of these are heads and of those 4, 2 come from fair coins.

If you kept on flipping the chosen coin and it kept on being heads, then each extra heads would increase your degree of belief that it was the rigged coin, over time towards (but not reaching) $1$.  This increase would also happen with the first heads (from $\frac 13$ before any flips) but the alternative suggests that it would not.

Your final statement assumes that all three possibilities are equally likely. They are not.
$P(Heads)=P(H\cap Fair_1)+P(H\cap Fair_2)+P(H\cap Rigged)$
$=P(H| Fair_1)\times P(Fair_1)+P(H| Fair_2)\times P(Fair_2)+P(H| Rigged)\times P(Rigged)$
$=\frac{1}{2}\times \frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{2}\times \frac{1}{3}+1 \times \frac{1}{3}$
$P(Heads)=\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{3}=\frac{2}{3}$
Now, $P(Rigged|Heads)=P(Rigged\cap Heads)\div P(Heads)$
$=\frac{1}{3} \div \frac{2}{3}$
$=\frac{1}{2}$
Which agrees with the result given in the first part of your question, so there is no problem.
